# Minimizing a function(2 Variable) in MATLAB

Tags: optimization, matlab, maxima-minima

I have a function $J(x_1,x_2)$ in MATLAB.
I have found this function using a number of prior computations.For the computation I have use symbolic toolbox,hence is very dirty.(Not posting it here.)

Now, I am trying to find the value of $x_1$ and $x_2$ for which the function has its minimum.

I have used the following commands:

```
fun = @(x)(the function); 
x0 = [0,0];  % Random points to start
x = fminsearch(fun,x0)
```

But I am getting the following:

```
Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded
     - increase MaxFunEvals option.
     Current function value: 0.000000 

x =

  1.0e+15 *

   1.2039    0.0000
```

I have searched for this and according to those:

Should I conclude that the function has no minima ?

Any hints please.

Thank You very much

Anupam

Comment: Is the function polynomial, at least?

Comment: For verification, it would be nice that you provide a surface plot of the function in $(x_1, x_2)$ coordinates. This could help to evaluate the difficulty of the optimization problem.